# Chrome Extension To Enable chat bot in all pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bots

We have created a internal bot for our organisation , is it possible to enable it in all website at right bottom of the webpage using chrome extension.

I explored a bit and was not able to find anything , is it even possible to do it or we should look for other alternatives rahter that using chrome extension

Comment: I would say yes it should be possible, but a lot would determine on the Chat bot.  is it Javascript also?   I have chrome extension that inserts html at the bottom of my page and run a quick command that creates html at the bottom of the page using a combination of Document.createElement, Document.createHTMLDocument().  Depends on the code of the chat bot as well.  Could you show some code?

Comment: @JasonOwens , i created a bot using azure bot chat framework and having been using there webchat (https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. First, you can rely on your manifest file to automatically inject your web bot code as a content script by matching to `*://*/*`.
Your other option is programmatic insertion from your background script, for this a possible way could be to create a listener for `chrome.tabs.onCreated` and `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` in your background script and in this listener then insert this code `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "your_web_bot_code.js", allFrames: true, runAt: "document_end"});`